# Дебагер в PHPStorm не подхватывает другие страницы

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Дебагер настроен, но дебажит он только индексную страницу он не останавливается на брек поинте который в контроллере а только останавливается на брекпоинтах в индексном файле, что тут не так?

Answer (score 5):

1. Убедитесь, что код контроллера действительно выполняется. Можно добавить в код контроллера какой-нибудь отладочный код, который покажет своё присутствие. Или можно бросить исключение и поймать его в режиме остановки на исключениях.
2. Убедитесь, что файлы каким-нибудь образом не продублированы, и что вы ставите точки останова именно на тех файлах, которые выполняются. У вас может быть несколько веток, какие-то файлы могут преобразовываться и тому подобное.
3. Воспользуйтесь функцией отладчика для входа внутрь и выхода из функций, чтобы добраться до интересующего вас кода. Если контроллер действительно выполняется, то до его кода можно добраться пошаговым выполнением кода из индексного файла.